# Windows version macros in windows drivers

Tags: winapi, wdk

`_WIN64` can be used to find the platform to be 32-bit or 64-bit.

Are there any macros available in drivers (kernel mode code) that can be used to tell the version of the operating system. XP, 2003, Vista or 7?

Comment: Do you want to know this at compile-time or at runtime?

Comment: since windows driver kit has a separate build environment for every version, knowing at compile time is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The info you need is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745.aspx).  Check out `SdkDdkVer.h` in your build environment.  Especially useful: [NTDDI_VERSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549459%28VS.85%29.aspx).